# need to know the topological property of the set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I can prove that $A$ is closed bounded, could any one tell me $A$ is connected and dense too?thank you.

[image]

> $A$ is the closure in $\mathcal C[0,1]$ of the set $B$ where
>   $$B=\{f\in\mathcal C^1[0,1]; |f(x)|\le1\text{ and }|f'(x)|\le1\text{ for all }x\in[0,1]\}.$$
>   Answer: closed, compact, connected, dense

Comment: Are you sure that it is $B$ that should be proven to have the mentioned properties, and not $A$?

Comment: @SimenK. edited, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compactness: [Arzela-Ascoli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzela-Ascoli_theorem).

Connectedness: the closure of a connected set is connected (note that $B$ is convex, hence so is $A$).

Since you didn't say dense *where* this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Well, since $A$ is compact, it is quite hard for it to be dense anywhere but itself :-)